# Assemble useful toolbox items

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to create a custom toolbox with useful elements for me.
The elements I use are all built-in, such as Archimate tools, SoaML and activity tools.

Is it possible to assemble them all to one toolbox?

When I create an MDG of a new tool set, I can only extend the common tools, such as class, component, package, etc. Where are the other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put them in a single MDG. To address elements from other MDGs you need to qualify them explicitly. E.g. for a `ArchiMate_BusinessActor` you need to write by hand `ArchiMate2::ArchiMate_BusinessActor`.

To find out the id (e.g. `Archimate2` in the above example) open the MDG file which is located in the EA program folder under `MDGTechnologies`. The second line holds the attribute `id` which is what you need.

To find the stereotype simply open the element properties.

`id` and `stereotype` concatenated with `::` form the specifier for the meta class.

EDIT (from user3165438): The`ArchiMate2::ArchiMate_BusinessActor` should be added to the toolbox page list.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it in `Whiteboard::Cylinder` element and it works.  I couldn't use it for `Strategic Modeling::Flow Chart::Process`. What about sub-toolboxes? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I guess you need to specify `Strategic Modeling::Process` (the profile name and the meta class). And once again: I don't understand your edit. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried `Strategic Modeling::Process` with no success. I tried also more combinations and still do not manage the formula. Any other hints? Re edit: Since it does harm and is more clear for me, I just added a comment.

Comment: Since you cross posted this on Sparx' forum (IIRC) you should add this to your question. I'll try to have a look later, but the Sparx guys (if they happen to read it) have more experience with those peculiarities.

Comment: Just one more try. There stereo is `FC_Process`. The id for the MDG is `StrategyMap` (you see that when editing the MDG file). So `StrategyMap::FC_Process` should work.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. This works now for `StrategyMap::FC_Process` but not for `StrategyMap::FC_DefinedProcess` or `StrategyMap::FC_Begin`. What thin the world that means?

Comment: Well, here it ends for me. If the Sparxians don't answer your question today/tomorrow write a mail to their support. This usually works like a charm. Don't forget to post their answer in that case and I'll cross post here.